# Is it possible to use GMB API to post product catalogue items?

Tags: product, google-my-business-api

I have been using Google My Business API but although I can create events and posts I can't create a product catalogue there. Is that even possible and if so what REST resource should be invoked?

Answer (score 4):

It's seemingly possible. Check it out the changelog for v4.2
https://developers.google.com/my-business/content/change-log#v42

> **Product Posts**
>
> A new Local Post type, conaining product related content (e.g. name,
>   price).

This would mean that you'd need to **use the resource accounts.locations.localPosts**. Something tells me they are still working on the reference page though because there is no product type. https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/rest/v4/accounts.locations.localPosts#localposttopictype

I'm trying to figure this out myself as well, I want to use the API for managing our GMB products in bulk.

**Try**

- Logging into GMB and create a product using the UI
- Use the API to list local posts for your location (accounts.locations.localPosts.list)
- Since products are a type of local post, they'd reveal their format in the list response (hopefully)
- Lastly use the API to create a local post mimicking the product format (accounts.locations.localPosts.create)

I'd much rather give you a formatted call but I wanted to confirm that people are using the API to manage products in bulk before getting into it. Please report any discoveries!